# Nullable parameters in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, value-type

I know similar questions have been asked already but I did not find any solution for my particular issue.

I have a generic class with a constructor like this:

```
public ClampedValue(T value, T? min = default, T? max = default)
```

I would like to be able to pass in an integer as T and optionally a min and a max. If min or max are null they are to be ignored. I already noticed that

```
public ClampedValue(T value, T? min = null, T? max = null)
```

is not possible, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I would expect T? = null to be valid but I get an error stating something about T not having standard conversion for null. I would understand T = null to be wrong because T can be a valueType, but T? explicitly asks for a nullable.

EDIT: Full class source

```
[Serializable]
    public class ClampedValue<T> : IClamp<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        internal T _value;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public T? Min { get; set; } = default;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public T? Max { get; set; } = default;

        public virtual T Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                if (Max is not null && value.CompareTo(Max) > 0)
                {
                    _value = Max;
                }
                else if (Min is not null && value.CompareTo(Min) < 0)
                {
                    _value = Min;
                }
                else
                {
                    _value = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public ClampedValue(T value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public ClampedValue(T value, [AllowNull] T? min = default, [AllowNull] T? max = default)
        {
            Min = min;
            Max = max;

            if (Min is not null && Max is not null)
            {
                if (Min.CompareTo(Max) >= 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("ERROR: Min has to be lower than max!", nameof(min));
                }
                if (value is null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("ERROR: Value cannot be null!", nameof(Value));
                }
            }

            Value = value;
            if (_value is null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Value remained nll after assignement!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can `T` be a struct only? Or a class only?

Comment: @Sweeper Ideally it should support any IComparable, if not then struct only

Comment: `T? min = default` would be valid, but not necessarily what you want (`default(int) == 0`). `T? min = null` would only work if a constraint of the form `where T : class` or `where T : struct` is added, since these have different representations for `T?`.

Comment: "I would like to be able to pass in an integer as T " please explain why you need a generic parameter. what are the usecases? sounds a little like an XY Problem

Comment: If struct only is acceptable, then just add a `where T: struct` constraint. Otherwise, you're going to have a hard time.

Comment: @Sweeper I added the entire source code for the class to the edit

Comment: Note that most types you'd be interested in passing here almost certainly *have* a minimum and maximum value, so simply not making them nullable is another option. If the caller then really wants (say) an unclamped `int` they'll have to pass `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` explicitly, which is arguably clearer than leaving out both parameters and getting a "clamped value" that isn't actually clamped at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I may just end up going that way, as mostly they are used with float and uint anyway.

Comment: With `float` the only "gotcha" is that you probably want to use `float.PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity` rather than `MaxValue` and `MinValue`, since "clamping" infinities to actual values would be a bad idea. So I guess in that case `null` *might* be considered clearer (and handling `NaN` is another concern).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Why would clamping to float.MaxValue be a bad idea? You are not supposed to ever go over that value in the first place. Actually I think it would be better to throw an exception if infinity even happened to come around, as that would mean something went VERY wrong in the app.

Comment: It might be a bad idea because `float.PositiveInfinity > float.MaxValue`, and "infinity" behaves differently in calculations from `MaxValue` (that's why "infinity" exists in the first place). Of course you can have exceptions instead, if in your particular domain you know infinities are not an issue or not desired, but if infinities are clamped during a multi-step calculation the end results might be very wrong.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah as I said, not working with infinites thankfully. The clamps are used for actuator configuration, so having an infinite maximum extension or acceleration could cause havok. I wanted them optional though as some servos may have limited range while others can have full rotation. I could still add two boolean flags to turn off the checks and just be done with that, but I though having them null when not used is the more elegant solution.